# analytic continuation of $I(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} dt /(1+ t )$

Tags: complex-analysis

The integral makes sense when $x> 0$. Or more, it defines an analytic function on the right half plane. Now, I want to extend into the left half plane. How to do it? I thought of dividing the domain $(0, \infty) $ into two parts, $(0,1) $ and $(1,\infty )$. But I cannot find an expression for the second part.

Answer (score 2):

Your integral is
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - xt} }}{{1 + xt}}dt}  = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - s} }}{{1 + s}}ds}  = \frac{{ - e \operatorname{Ei}( - 1)}}{x} = \frac{{0.5963 \ldots }}{x},
$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the exponential integral. Analytic continuation is now obvious.

Comment: okay, you convert the original problem to another equally difficult problem. But anyway, it at least shows that the problem must have been well studied.

Comment: I do not think that the recirprocal function is difficult to understand. It is analytic everywhere except at $x=0$. Do you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: sorry, I made an error in the integrand. It is $e^{-xt}/(1+t)$ not $e^{-xt}/(1+xt)$.

Answer (score 1):

> Please don't change your questions this way.

For $s>0$ let $$I(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-st}}{1+ t }dt, \qquad E_1(s)= \int_s^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$

With (two) change of variable you get $$I(s)=e^s E_1(s)$$
Then use that $$E_1(s)-E_1(1)+\log s= \int_s^1 \frac{e^{-u}-1}{u}du$$ is entire.